# devextreme - calculate cell value based on another calculated cell

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular, dx-data-grid

In my Devextreme dependent Angular application, I have four columns (A, B, C, and D) in my dxDataGrid.

C is a calculated column with formula A+B and D is another calculated column that has a dependency on C and the formula is say C*2.

I have used `calculateCellValue` to calculate the value for C and it works perfectly fine.

However, when I used the same `calculateCellValue` handler function to calculate the value for column D, it returns an empty cell.

Does this mean we can not define a calculated column that is based on another calculated column?

Answer (score 0):

The value for column **C** you calculate inside the `calculateCellValue` method does not persist in your data source. Thats why you can't use this value to calculate further.
You could do the same calculation in the `calculateCellValue` method for column **D** as you did in column **C** + your extra calculation.

However i would prefer to extend the data source and calculate everything beforehand. This would also improve performance because the `calculateCellValue` method executes multiple times for each row when rendered, sorted, filtered or summarised.